# Sufficient condition for linear interpolation of a 3D array to be a cumulative distribution function?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $z[i, j, k]\in [0, 1], 0\leq i, j, k \leq n$ be an array satisfying:

1. $z[i, j, k]\geq z[i-1, j, k],z[i, j-1, k], z[i, j, k-1] $
2. $z[i, j, k]=0$ if $i=0$ or $j=0$ or $k=0$
3. $z[n, n, n]=1$.

Now consider the natural linear interpolation of $z$,  $F:[0, 1]^3 \to [0, 1]$ from the discrete $n\times n \times n$ lattice to $[0,1]^3$.

**Question:**

What additional conditions do I need to impose on $z$ so that $F$ is a valid cumulative distribution function on $[0,1]^3$. Specifically, I need to gurantee

$$V_F([u_1, v_1]\times [u_2,v_2]\times [u_3, v_3]) \geq 0$$ for alll $0\leq u_i\leq v_i\leq 1$, where $V_F$ is the volume of $F$ on the box $[u_1, v_1]\times [u_2, v_2]\times [u_3, v_3]$.

Comment: Actually, I realised the solution, but not sure if anyone would be interested in the solution. I can type it up if anyone's interested.